# Sistema de respuestas Vuejs + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo un problema al querer actualizar las respuestas de una pregunta que se realizo, el detalle esta que al responder a la pregunta esta respuesta no se actualiza en el listado de respuesta que esta en la pregunta.

Dejo el código para que lo chequeen y me digan que estoy haciendo mal.

**Listado de respuesta de la pregunta hecha:**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                    <replys v-for="reply in ask.replys" :reply="reply" :key="ask.id"></replys>
                </div>
```

Form para responder a la pregunta

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <reply-form v-on:answer="updateReplys" :ask="ask"></reply-form>
                </div>
```

Los componentes:

Aqui Cargo las preguntas con las respuestas dadas:

```
<script>
    import Replys from './Replys.vue'
    import ReplyForm from  './ReplyForm.vue'
    export default {
        // Options / Data
        created () {
            this.getAskQuestion();
        },
        components: {
            Replys,
            ReplyForm
        },
        data () {
            return {
                replys: [],
                askQuestions: [],
            }
        },
         methods: {
             updateReplys (replys) {
                 this.replys.push(replys);
             },
             getAskQuestion () {
                 axios.get('/paciente/questions')
                     .then(response => {
                         this.askQuestions = response.data.data;
                     });
             }

         },


    }
</script>
```

Aqui el componete Replys

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center-xs">
        <div class="list-group-item md-whiteframe-z0 b-l-primary">
            <a href="" class="pull-left w-40 m-r"><img :src="'/user/'+reply.user.id+'/photo'" class="img-responsive img-circle"></a>
            <div class="clear">
                <a href="" class="font-bold block"></a>
                {{ reply.body }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script >
    export default {

         props: ['reply'],

    }
</script>
```

Aqui el component ReplysForm

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center-xs">
        <div class="list-group-item md-whiteframe-z0 b-l-success">
            <a href="" class="pull-left w-40 m-r"><img :src="user.photo" class="img-responsive img-circle"></a>
            <div class="clear">
                <div class="md-form-group">
                    <form class="" action="" @submit.prevent="createComment(ask)">
                        <textarea class="md-input" rows="2" v-model="body"></textarea>

                        <button md-ink-ripple="" type="submit" class="md-btn md-flat m-b btn-fw text-info waves-effect">Responder</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="">
    export default {

         data () { return {
             user: [],
             body:[]
         } },
        props: ['ask'],

         methods: {
             getUser() {
                 axios.get('/user')
                     .then(response => {
                         this.user = response.data;
                     });
             },
             createComment(ask){
                 axios.post('/paciente/questions/replys',{body: this.body, ask_question_id: ask.id, user_id: user_id}).then(response => {
                     this.$emit('answer', response.data.replys);
                     this.body = ""
                 });

             }
         },

         created () {
             this.getUser()
         },

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Estas seguro que si está entrando en el método de `updateReplys`? confirmalo, colocando un `console.log` antes de hacer el push a tus `replys` y tambien al momento de hacer la petición en `createComment` deberias de verificar lo mismo, y me comentas que te aparece en la consola cuando lo haces con cada uno, para seguirte ayudando

Comment: Esta considerando que `this` cambia su comportamiento según su ámbito? Puede revisar esta documentación: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo es un problema de reactividad, hace poco tuve un problema similar y si revisas esta sección de la documentación
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

muestra el siguiente problema

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  }
})
// `vm.a` is now reactive

vm.b = 2
// `vm.b` is NOT reactive
```

como a: está inicializado es reactivo, pero b que es insertado dentro del componente no es reactivo por que no existía y vue no asigno getters y setters para esto, entonces no se están envíando las notificaciones de cambios, entonces debemos de utilizar

```
Vue.set(object, key, value)
```

para que vue generé los getters y setters, y sea reactivo.

entonces el objecto sería el que estas utilizando en data, la llave sería una llave no existente cuando se inicializó y value sería el nuevo valor.
entonces podrías reemplazar

```
    getAskQuestion () {
             axios.get('/paciente/questions')
                 .then(response => {
                     this.askQuestions = response.data.data;
                 });
         }
```

por

```
    getAskQuestion () {
         axios.get('/paciente/questions')
             .then(response => {
                 Vue.set(this.askQuestion, 'data', response.data.data)
             });
     }
```

accediendo de esta manera

```
this.askQuestion.data
```

o podrías revisar si lo puedes insertar directamente en this

```
    getAskQuestion () {
         axios.get('/paciente/questions')
             .then(response => {
                 Vue.set(this, 'askQuestion', response.data.data)
             });
     }
```

nota si declaras en

```
data () { return { askQuestion }}
```

no va a funcionar la  no tiene que existir el objeto para que sea insertado con las propiedades reactivas